# Стили в vaadin 8

Tags: java, vaadin

Недавно начал работать c vaadin 8, и все никак не получается менять стили.
Например я пишу свой стиль в файл mytheme.scss ,далее запись переносится в style.css,но на этом все, я добавляю его например в Label методом 
setStyleName(class_name);
 и ничего не меняется.

Comment: а можно чуть подробнее узнать о Вашем проекте? Как Вы пытались установить свой стиль?

Comment: Опубликовал ответ в общем виде. Если это не поможет, то опубликуйте подробнее информацию о том, с каким стеком технологий Вы работаете и как сконфигурирован Ваш проект.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Откройте в браузере "Инструменты разработчика"
2. Перейдите на вкладку "Network"
3. Отфильтруйте запросы на загрузку каскадных таблиц стилей с использованием кнопки CSS
4. Убедитесь, что в списке запросов присутствует запрос `http://mydomain/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/styles.css`

**Если данный запрос присутствует, но статус ответа != 200**
значит у Вас проблема с конфигурацией веб-приложения, и в частности проблема с отдачей ресурсов.
В разных стеках данная проблема решается по-разному.
Я чаще использую Spring, и для того чтобы отдать кастомные Vaadin ресурсы использую следующее правило в классе настройки MVC:

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/VAADIN/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/VAADIN/");
```

Сам класс выглядит примерно так:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.vaadin.spring.boot")
public class MVCConfig  extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
        // ...    
        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
            // ...
            registry.addResourceHandler("/VAADIN/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/VAADIN/");
            // ...                   
        }
        // ...    
}
```

мои ресурсы при этом лежат в `src\main\resources\VAADIN\themes\mytheme\*`

**Если же запрос на загрузку Ваших стилей отсутствует**
то скорее всего Вы не установили свою тему в Vaadin приложении.
По умолчанию Vaadin 8 использует тему Valo и в таком случае, в списке запросов должен присутствовать запрос `http://mydomain/VAADIN/themes/valo/styles.css`.
В данном случае Vaadin не будет загружать стили Вашей темы, поскольку он ничего о ней не знает.

Для того чтобы установить свою тему необходимо проставить аннотацию `@Theme` над Вашим UI-классом:

```
@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {
    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Также если Вы не хотите полностью заменять текущую тему, а лишь добавить пару-тройку дополнительных стилей, Вы можете просто указать дополнительные ресурсы с помощью аннотаций `@StyleSheet`, `@JavaScript` в UI - классе.(*Путь к ресурсам может отличаться в зависимости от конфигурации Вашего проекта - будьте осторожны*)

```
@StyleSheet("app://../VAADIN/themes/valo/additional.css")
@JavaScript("app://../VAADIN/themes/valo/additional.js")
public class VaadinUI extends UI {
   // ...
}
```